# When using the singular pronoun "they", should the verb be in the 3rd person singular or the 3rd person plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

> A person who has perfectly good relations with their father, who loves
>   their father, and has a great respect for them, can never shout at him
>   like that.

> A person who have perfectly good relations with their father, who love
>   their father, and have a great respect for them, can never shout at
>   him like that.

Which one's correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The singular verb *has* should definitely be used in the sentence as you have written it. I would not however use 'them' to refer to the father too, since you know that the father is a 'him'. There are, though, things that are slightly incorrect in the sentence. Personally I would say:

*A person who has perfectly good relations with their father, who loves their father, and has a great respect for **him, could** never shout at him like that.*

But please note that, in your sentence, the verb 'has' is not actually being used with the pronoun 'they'as the subject. In the first instance your subject is *a person who* which clearly takes *has* as its verb. If however you were to use *they* as a singular subject, meaning 'he' or 'she', then you would use the plural verb, such as in:

*As regards the person I have just mentioned, and as I understand it, they are going to be charged with obstructing the course of justice.*

You would never correctly say *they is going to be charged.*

Comment: @ws2thank you, could you also please answer my other question?

Comment: @user72745 I'm not sure I follow you. What was your 'other' question?

Comment: "the father is a 'him'" - what if the father has an alternative gender identity? Won't it offend them?

Comment: @olegst I am not sufficiently liberated as to regard a *father* as anything but a *him*. And I believe I carry at least 99% of people with me at the moment - but I realise it could change.